# I don't understand the logic in this linear algebra proof. Can you help me think through it?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

statement (b): Every $b ∈ R^m$ is a linear combination of $a1, a2, . . . , an$, the columns of A.

statement (c):The columns of $A$ span $R^m$, int other words (span{$a1, a2, . . . , an$}$ = R^m$.

PROOF that $(b) ⇒ (c)$

For every $b ∈ R^m$, statement (b) implies that $b ∈ span${$a1, . . . , an$}.

Hence $R^m ⊆ span${$a1, . . . , an$}.

On the other hand, because $a1, . . . , an ∈ R^m$, we have $span${$a1, . . . , an$}$ ⊆
R^m$.

Hence $R^m = span${$a1, . . . , an$}.

.

Specifically, I don't understand the first two lines: If for every A in B and A is also in C, how does this imply that B is a subset of C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **definition** of the statement

$$X\subseteq Y$$

is the following:

> $\forall x: x\in X \implies y \in Y$.

---

Therefore, proving the statement

$$\mathbb R^m\subseteq\mathrm{span}\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$$

is, *by definition*, equivalent to proving the statement

$$\forall b: b\in\mathbb R^m\implies b\in\mathrm{span}\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}.$$